# DYN for Robert Asprin's Myth Adventures?

Tags: fantasy-genre

Terry Pratchett's *Discworld* series has the [Annotated Pratchett File](http://lspace-us.puntbow.net.au/ftp/words/apf/apf).

*The Simpsons* has episodic ["did you notice" (DYN) posts](http://www.snpp.com/episodes/).

Is there an equivalent for Robert Asprin's popular *Myth Adventures* series, and if so, where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

The closest I know of / can find is this site, the [Nitpickers' Guide to Robert Asprin's Myth-series](http://www.sarangworld.com/mythpickf.php3). It is incomplete and hasn't been updated in a few years, but still has some interesting content.